# Override Predef's implicit conversions

Tags: scala

I have multiple methods that return a java.lang.Integer, which is then implicitly converted to an Int using Scala's Predef implicit conversions, here is how it is written [there](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala):

```
implicit def Integer2int(x: java.lang.Integer): Int = x.intValue
```

This conversion is not satisfying to me, I would like something along the lines of:

```
implicit def Integer2int(x: java.lang.Integer): Int = 
  Option(x).getOrElse(new Integer(0)).intValue
```

as the `Integer` can sometimes be `null` and in that case Predef's implicit conversion returns null as well and I would like it to be 0 instead.

I wrote my own conversion but I keep getting errors saying that this declaration is ambiguous given that it is already declared in Predef.

My question is, is there a way to actually override Predef's implicit conversions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the `Predef` import like this:

```
import scala.Predef.{Integer2int => _}
```

And then just redefine `Integer2int` as you wish.

Funny proof: http://ideone.com/R7Zyfd

Comment: This works just fine, just one remark: When doing the import inside an object, what you suggested works, however, if you need to do this outside an object, you need to write it this way: `import scala.Predef.{Integer2int => _,_}`