# Scala implicit def resolution by number of parameters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have two implicit conversions that add an `apply` method.

```
implicit def f1(foo: Foo) = new {
  def apply(x: Int) = ???
}

implicit def f2(foo: Foo) = new {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = ???
}
```

But I can't use them, because the compiler complains about ambiguous implicit conversions

```
foo(1) // compile error
```

Why does it complain if it is clear which one should be used?

Comment: You have `implicit def f1(foo: Foo) ` and `implicit def f2(foo: Foo) `. So yeah, it is not clear at this point, even though the created objects would have apply()s with different signatures. Why not just put both apply()s into one implicit def?

Comment: @slouc Because one apply is from Predef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem lies in existing implicit inside `Predef`, you should disable `Predef` import like described here: [Override Predef's implicit conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816884/override-predefs-implicit-conversions)

By example, let's try to make new `apply` function for `String`.

```
scala> implicit def stringToFunction(s: String) = new {
     |   def apply(x1: Int) = ???
     | }
stringToFunction: (s: String)AnyRef{def apply(x1: Int): Nothing}

scala> "123"(15)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("123")
 required: ?{def apply: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
 and method stringToFunction of type (s: String)AnyRef{def apply(x1: Int): Nothing}
 are possible conversion functions from String("123") to ?{def apply: ?}
       "123"(15)
       ^
<console>:13: error: String("123") does not take parameters
       "123"(15)
            ^
```

So, we should disable `augmentString` import from `Predef`:

```
scala> import Predef.{augmentString => _, _}
import Predef.{augmentString=>_, _}

scala> "123"(15)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("123")
 required: ?{def apply: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method wrapString in class LowPriorityImplicits of type (s: String)scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString
 and method stringToFunction of type (s: String)AnyRef{def apply(x1: Int): Nothing}
 are possible conversion functions from String("123") to ?{def apply: ?}
       "123"(15)
       ^
<console>:14: error: String("123") does not take parameters
       "123"(15)
            ^
```

Let's disable `wrapString` too, that will finally achieve what we wanted to do:

```
scala> import Predef.{augmentString => _, wrapString => _, _}
import Predef.{augmentString=>_, wrapString=>_, _}

scala> "123"(15)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:284)
  at $anon$1.apply(<console>:12)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  ... 31 elided
```

You can do the same for implicit conversions from your class `Foo`, following compiler complaints about ambigious conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! And my apologies for being a subject of the XY problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should include both `apply()`'s into one implicit:

```
implicit def f1(foo: Foo) = new {
  def apply(x: Int) = ???
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = ???
}
```

From http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions:

> An implicit conversion from type S to type T is defined by an implicit value which has function type S => T, or by an implicit method convertible to a value of that type.

So, you should have exactly **one** implicit method converting `Foo` to function.

How it works in your example case:

1. Compiler sees `foo(1)` invocation.
2. It replaces it with `foo.apply(1)`.
3. It founds, that class `Foo` doesn't have method `apply` and tries to find implicit conversion to class with this method.
4. It founds two conversions, `f1` and `f2`, and gives up on it.

Comment: I can't merge those implicits, cause one of them is in `Predef`.

Comment: @Yaroslav I guess, you should update your question to be more specific then

Comment: @Yaroslav which version of Scala do you use and what is exactly the `Foo` class which you try to implicitly convert?

Comment: @Yaroslav it actually doesn't really matter, what your `Foo` class is, algorithm of disabling `Predef` imports is the same anyways. Check my another answer